# Schauder Basis on (non normed) Vector Space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, schauder-basis

The information about Basis (over infinite dimensional vector spaces) in the texts that i am reading assume that we are already dealing with a Hilbert Space and an orthonormal system. I am trying to understand how far we can abstract the notion of Schauder basis and what we can infer,

from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis

"
Let V denote a Banach space over the field F. A Schauder basis is a sequence ${b_n}$ of elements of V such that for every element $v \in V$ there exists a unique sequence ${\alpha_n}$ of scalars in F so that

\begin{equation}
 {\displaystyle v=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\alpha _{n}b_{n}}
\end{equation}
where the convergence is understood with respect to the norm topology, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
 \lim _{n\to \infty }\left\|v-\sum _{k=0}^{n}\alpha _{k}b_{k}\right\|_{V}=0
\end{equation}
Schauder bases can also be defined analogously in a general topological vector space.
"

Suppose we have an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ such that every vector $v \in V$ can be expressed as the first equation.
Here is my question:

1. If we do not want to assume $V$ is a Banach space, what assumptions must be made on the vector space $V$ such that the set of coefficients ${\alpha_n}$ uniquely determine the vectors? i.e. if two vectors have the same set of coefficients, then the vectors are equal. is vector addition and scalar multiplication sufficient? i ask because convergence mentioned above is with respect to the norm topology, but the last line does not mention anything about the vector space having a norm.

Comment: You don't need a norm to say a sequence $v_n$ in $V$ converges to some vector $v$. You just need a topology.

Comment: See here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/basis+in+functional+analysis